# html button styles

Tags: html, button

How can you add multiple styles to the one button...this doesn't work.

```
<button style="background:red", "cursor:pointer">click me</button>
```

I have tried:

- `style="background:red", "cursor:pointer"`
- `style="background:red" "cursor:pointer"`
- `style="background:red" style="cursor:pointer"`

is it possible to combine multiple styles?

Comment: you should take a look at how to properly declare inline styles... Have a look at this: http://is.gd/jUKeOY

Comment: @Dan or how to properly avoid them...

Comment: @AlienWebguy - yeah that too...

Comment: Eschewing `style` attributes is an approach, not a rule (for instance, this page's source has several `style` attributes). The answer to question is how to format properties, not how to avoid `style` attributes altogether (which is an opinion).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should really use a css class and avoid styling DOM nodes inline:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
        background-color:red;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>

<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Even more ideally you'd create a CSS file.

CSS (style.css) :

```
.btn {
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML :

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Separate properties with `;` and put all properties between the same set of quotes:

```
<button style="background:red; cursor:pointer">click me</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/GcY97/

The same goes for CSS class declarations:

```
button {
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You separate all html style properties with a semicolon - **;**

```
style="background: red; cursor: pointer;"
```

Comment: Your code worked too, but the classes is a neater way. I didn't know that you could do it that way.